# Recovered .ssh/authorized_keys file, but still get Permission Denied (Public Key) message

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh

I Lost public key access to my Ubuntu 12.04 instance. I'm using the correct login credentials "ubuntu@myip-address", and I tried launching a new instance (attaching the key in question to it) and it works with the new instance. I then realized, after reading other possible causes suggesting it could have something to do with the .ssh/authorized_keys file, that I accidentally deleted all the files in my ubuntu home folder (forgetting about the hidden files at the time).

I tried attaching and mounting my "corrupt" volume to the new instance I launched, and recursively copied the new instance's Ubuntu directory into my corrupt volumes home directory, so my corrupt /home/ubuntu directory contains:

.  ..  .bash_history  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .cache  .profile  .ssh  .sudo_as_admin_successful

Just like new (I think). After attaching and mounting it back to my original instance, even though all the files I deleted are restored, including the proper public key info in the .ssh/authorized_keys file, I still get Permission Denied (Public Key) message. Should this have worked?

I tried reattaching the corrupt volume to my new instance just to double check that my work was still intact. Not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have neglected `-p` or `-a` when copying. Make sure the permissions are correct:

```
chmod 700 .ssh/
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Everything was owned by root, I guess since I copied it with sudo. Recopying with -a did the trick. Thank you very much!!!